# Create another URL in Joomla 3 to same address

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

Is possible create a URL redirection in Joomla3 without extension/component?

For example, I have the URL:

```
mydomain.com/menu-alias/item
```

I need to make another URL to redirect to mydomain.com/menu-alias/item  like:

```
/mydomain.com/short-url
```

Will I need some component/extension? or I can make it from Joomla3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Redirect component.

See [http://docs.joomla.org/Help33:Components_Redirect_Manager](http://docs.joomla.org/Help33%3aComponents_Redirect_Manager) for details.

Comment: That component did not worked correctly.. I fixed it... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A common practice on Joomla for these types of "shortcut" URLs is to create a "Hidden" [menu](http://docs.joomla.org/Menu) in the [Menu Manager](http://docs.joomla.org/Help25%3aMenus_Menu_Manager) and simply create a menu item in that with the alias you desire.

If you decide to do this and you have multiple menu's linking to the same content I would strongly suggest that you decide which one is the canonical path and then make any other menu items of the "[Menu Item Alias](http://docs.joomla.org/Help33%3aMenus_Menu_Item_Menu_Item_Alias)" type.